# Will the last minimum number sql connections in connection pool be alive forever if non uses the app?

Tags: sql, connection, pool

I have set connection pool minimum pool size to 10; After certain time lets say there are at least 10 sql connections in the pool. If no one uses the application there after, will sql connection remain open forever because minimum pool size is set.

IN my application users typically use during office hours for a period two weeks and then may not return for months. Connections are held per database

Answer (score 0):

In the case of SQL Server, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx indicates:

> If MinPoolSize is either not specified in the connection string or is
>   specified as zero, the connections in the pool will be closed after a
>   period of inactivity. However, if the specified MinPoolSize is greater
>   than zero, the connection pool is not destroyed until the AppDomain is
>   unloaded and the process ends. Maintenance of inactive or empty pools
>   involves minimal system overhead.

So because you are specifying MinPoolSize of 10, the pool will not be destroyed.

However, connections will still time out if they are idle, so I would expect you to be left with 10 connections per connection string, all marked as invalid. These should not put any load on the database, assuming the connections are timed out:

> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has
>   been idle for approximately 4-8 minutes, or if the pooler detects that
>   the connection with the server has been severed. Note that a severed
>   connection can be detected only after attempting to communicate with
>   the server. If a connection is found that is no longer connected to
>   the server, it is marked as invalid. Invalid connections are removed
>   from the connection pool only when they are closed or reclaimed.
>
> If a connection exists to a server that has disappeared, this
>   connection can be drawn from the pool even if the connection pooler
>   has not detected the severed connection and marked it as invalid. This
>   is the case because the overhead of checking that the connection is
>   still valid would eliminate the benefits of having a pooler by causing
>   another round trip to the server to occur. When this occurs, the first
>   attempt to use the connection will detect that the connection has been
>   severed, and an exception is thrown.